# Format JSON and save it using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a couple of JSON files that I generated using a tool. The problem is, even thought this JSONs are valid, they don't have any indentation at all.

I already tried something like this:

```
fs.readdir(path, function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
    } 
    files.forEach((file) => {
        const pathToFile =  `../jsonFiles/${file}`;
        fs.readFile(pathToFile, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
            fs.writeFile(pathToFile, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)), (err) => {
                 if (err) {
                     console.log(err)
                }
            });

        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)` instead of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))` and also add `utf8` to the options of `fs.writeFile`:

```
fs.readdir(path, function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
    } 
    files.forEach((file) => {
        const pathToFile =  `../jsonFiles/${file}`;
        fs.readFile(pathToFile, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
            fs.writeFile(pathToFile, JSON.stringify(data, null, 4), 'utf8', (err) => {
                 if (err) {
                     console.log(err)
                }
            });

        });
    });
});
```

**Edit:** I read your question again. I think you switched `parse` and `stringify` of the data, that you read as a string. I fixed it:

```
fs.readdir(path, function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
    } 
    files.forEach((file) => {
        const pathToFile =  `../jsonFiles/${file}`;
        fs.readFile(pathToFile, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
            fs.writeFile(pathToFile, JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data), null, 4), 'utf8', (err) => {
                 if (err) {
                     console.log(err)
                }
            });

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. In my case, this only adds a ton of '\' characters into the json

Comment: @Anon I have edited my answer as well. Please have a look. I think I found the real issue in context.

Comment: Thank you! Btw: You can use `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data), null, '\t')` to use tab to intend instead of four spaces.

Comment: Oh yes, that would be great. I really ignored the fact that I received the data as a string. Thanks for taking your time.